# Mysql performance of repeated count

Tags: sql, count

I need to fetch for each blog article, number of comments and I currently use this SQL

```
select 
id as article_id,
title,
content,
pic,
(select count(id) as comments from article_comments where
article_comments.article_parent_id = article_id group by article_id) as comments
from articles limit 1000);
```

This query has some significant delay compared to query without the ***count(id)*** subquery. The delay is about roughly 2 - 4 seconds for 1000 selected articles. Is there a way to improve performance of this query?

Answer (score 0):

Using count for big data will create a delay increasingly. In order to improve getting the number of comments in an article, create an attribute in the article table called `comment_count`. And everytime someone enters a comment the number will be increased by 1 in the corresponding article record. In that way, when you want to retrieve the article, you don't have to count the comments every time you load the page, it will be just an attribute.

Comment: Good idea. It seems this will be the solution, but I still wanted to know whether there was a way to improve SQL performance before doing this method.

Comment: @ahojvole You can't get the number of comments if they are not stored somewhere, so every time you want to load an article, you need to get the number of comments at runtime using count, which will create the delay for counting. Btw that's how forums use to keep track of the number of posts, replies etc ...

Comment: I noticed there is big difference between not doing the count at all and doing any number of counts. 10 counts and 1000 counts take about the same time for some reason.

Comment: Well this is another question that needs examples of queries and explanation of the table structure and records numbers and engine usage. But of course if you don't use count it will be much much faster than having it in a query

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select id as article_id, title, content, pic,
       (select count(id) as comments
        from article_comments
        where article_comments.article_parent_id = articles.article_id
        group by article_id
       ) as comments
from articles
limit 1000;
```

First, the `group by` is unnecessary.  Second, the index `article_comments(article_parent_id)` should help.  The final query might look like this:

```
select a.id as article_id, a.title, a.content, a.pic,
       (select count(*) as comments
        from article_comments ac
        where ac.article_parent_id = a.article_id
       ) as comments
from articles a
limit 1000;
```

Note that this also introduces table aliases.  Those make the query easier to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if circumstances allow it, it is much faster to make 1st sql query then extract required ids from it and make 2nd sql query with in() operator instead of joining tables / nesting queries.

```
select id as article_id, title, content, pic from articles limit 1000
```

At this point we need to declare string variable that is going to contain set of ids that will go into in() operator in next query.

```
<?php $in = '1, 2, 3, 4,...,1000'; ?>
```

Now we select comment count for a set of previously fetched article ids.

```
select count(*) from article_comments where article_id in ($in)
```

This method is slightly messier in terms of php code, because at his point we need *$articles* array containing article data and *$comments['article_id']* array containing count of comments for each article.

Contrary to improvement in performance this method is messier for php code and makes it impossible to search for values in second or any next table. 
This method is hence only applicable if performance is key and no other operations are required.